mock libc functions in rust
In my rust code, I am using several functions from libc. In my testcases I want to block those calls to libc and supply my own mock functions. I am new to rust so not sure how to get it right.
I have this small code that uses shm_open (as an example) and I have supplied my own stub function
use libc::{c_int, c_char, size_t, mode_t};
use libc::{O_RDWR, S_IROTH, S_IRUSR, S_IWOTH, S_IWUSR};

use std::mem;
#[cfg(not(test))]
use libc::shm_open;
#[cfg(test)]
fn shm_open(
    name: *const c_char, 
    oflag: i32, 
    mode: u32
) -> c_int{
    42 as c_int
}
const SHM_NAME: *const c_char = b"/ptp\0".as_ptr() as *const c_char;
const SHM_SIZE: size_t = mem::size_of::<u32>();
struct Consumer {
    s_value: c_int,
    s_data: u32,
}

trait GuestConsumer{
    fn new() -> Self;
}

impl GuestConsumer for Consumer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let shm_fd = unsafe {
            shm_open(
                SHM_NAME,
                O_RDWR,
                (S_IRUSR | S_IROTH | S_IWUSR | S_IWOTH) as mode_t,
            )
        };
        Self {
            s_value: shm_fd,
            s_data: 0
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests{
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_new(){
        let value  = Consumer::new();
        println!("s_value: {:?}", value.s_value);
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

This is working but I want to use a mocking library to mock shm_open function so that I can return different values in different testcases.
Can you please show me how to do that.
I tried the following but I am getting errors:
use mockall::*;
use mockall::predicate::*;

#[cfg(not(test))]
use libc::shm_open;
#[cfg(test)]
use dummy_libc::shm_open;    // error: not directly importable

#[allow(dead_code, non_camel_case_types)]
#[cfg(test)]
#[automock]
pub trait dummy_libc{
    fn shm_open(
        name: *const c_char, 
        oflag: c_int, 
        mode: mode_t
    )-> c_int;
}

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
So my question is how do I use mockall to mock my libc functions

Please do not ask the same question multiple times, instead you can [edit] it to add more details.
